# How to add .framework native references to Nuget Package

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.ios, nuget

I built a Xamarin Binding project for an existing Swift library and I am now trying to create a Nuget Package to distribute it.

The library has three native references to Swift frameworks and I don't see any option to include them. When I try to look inside the Nuget package, I don't see them. When I try to compile an app that uses the package it crashes because it can't find the native framework.

Any idea on how to solve the problem ?

Thank you

Comment: You will want to include them via another nuget (see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Swift4/ for how it is done) otherwise if someone else adds a nuget that also hardcodes the inclusion of Swift frameworks or uses ones from Flash3001 or another source .. then the xamarin.ios project will completely fail to package properly.... if this nuget is for private distribution then just review Flash3001's swift nugets on Github to see how its done...

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was that my native references were not correctly referenced...

Comment: @WitoldW How did you resolve this. I have a Swift Framework which also include other frameworks. I am able to create Xamarin Binding and all works fine on Device but when uploading to AppStore either it get rejected (ITMS-90205, ITMS-90206) or crashes on launch due to Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib | Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E89A57E1-92E5-490E-8B85-23A2171F916F/abc.app/Frameworks/CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift | Reason: image not found.   Can you help on this?

Comment: @ArunGupta
I haven't tested it but I think you'll find the solution in [this article](https://medium.com/@Flash3001/binding-swift-libraries-xamarin-ios-ff32adbc7c76). See point number 7: "Include SwiftSupport to push App to AppStore".